# Writing Django authentication/login logic with sessions

Tags: django, django-sessions

I'm still pretty new to Django and I'm looking to write a login method. What's the best logic for doing that and storing the info in a session so a user can maintain their login?

I have a model for authentication which looks like this:

```
class User(models.Model):
    email_address = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128) # sha512 of password w/salt
    password_salt = models.CharField(max_length=128) # sha512 of random number as salt
```

Essentially, I'd write a login method for a view like this:

```
@ratelimit_post(minutes = 1, requests = 5, key_field = 'email_address')
def login(request):
    requestedUser = User.objects.get(email_address=request.POST['email_address'])

    if requestedUser == None:
        fail_no_user()

    passwordHash = sha512(request.POST['password'] + requestedUser.password_salt)

    if requestedUser.password != passwordHash:
        fail_wrong_password()
    else:
        request.session['user_id'] = user.id
        request.session['is_auth'] = True
        success_login()
```

Is this a secure way of processing logins and sessions with Django? Since I'm kind of still new, I'm not sure whether this is an accepted approach. Is there anything security and performance-wise which I'm missing here?

Comment: Django comes with an authentication module. Have you tried that?

Comment: I need to use my own models, though. Will it work like that? It seems that you have to use their models.

Comment: do you see anything wrong with that model? I guess your question arises from the fact that you want to have more info/custom for the users in that model. Instead you could have a model called UserProfile which has a OneToOne relationship with the Django inbuilt User model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best option is to create your own backend.

See the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend

> Writing an authentication backend
>
> An authentication backend is a
>   class that implements two methods: get_user(user_id) and
>   authenticate(**credentials).

Answer (score 0):

Django comes with a very simple and powerful authentication system, [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) is the official doc.